# How to lay a layout over another android

Tags: android

I've followed [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270319-how-to-create-a-slide-in-menulist-like-in-facebook-app/) guide to make the sliding menu like the facebook app has.

When the `Button` is pressed, a new `Layout` shows from the left of the screen. But it pushes the orginal `Layout` with elements to the right of the screen. How can I make the `Layout` lay over the orginal `Layout`?

See the link for code samples. Thanks!

**Let me rephrase my question**

When I press the button, the text of the button, and the button itself will be pushed to one side, and aligned vertically. How can I just push the button "out of the screen"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To overlap layout/views above each other, you need to use [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). It sets the visibility of view (e.g. z-index in CSS) in the order as they are defined.

Comment: Do you have any examples? Thanks!

Comment: [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/) is a good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are adding the new layout to the parent layout which is why its pushing the original layout out of the way. You need to add the new layout to the original layout and it will lay in the original layout.